# Why is a Hyperplane called a "Hyper"plane?

Tags: geometry, self-learning

I just had this curious question. In other fields, the word "hyper" is actually used to refer to something which is "over; beyond; above" as defined by Google. An example of such terms would be Hyperglycaemia, defined by Wikipedia as:

> a condition in which an excessive amount of glucose circulates in the blood plasma.

Or Hypersonic, defined by Google as:

> relating to speeds of more than five times the speed of sound.

So, my question is, what would be the motive to give a Hyperplane such a name when it is defined as :

> a subspace of one dimension **less** than its ambient space

Comment: It is called a hyperplane because it is a *higher-dimensional* generalization of a *plane*, a two-dimensional subspace in the dimensions. See also *hypercube*, *hypersphere*, *hyperoctant*, etc.

Comment: Technically you can still talk about hyperplanes in $2$-d geometry: it's just that they also happen to be lines. One could call these hypo-planes if they wanted to maintain a distinction between lines and their duals :)

Comment: We can define hyperplanes as subspaces of codimension 1, from which it follows that hyperlines are subspaces of codimension two.

Answer (score 3):

Adding hyper- helps the listener know that it is like a plane, and yet it might be more than just an ordinary 2-d plane.

From 3-d geometry, we think of planes as being 2 dimensional things in a 3 dimensional world. In regular Euclidean geometry, there is a unique plane normal to a line through a given point. Similarly, there is a unique line through a given point on a plane that's normal to the plane. We want to take this line-plane connection through to higher dimensions. That's why the definition of "hyperplane" says it is $n-1$ dimensional, because it is the orthogonal complement to a $1$ dimensional piece of the space.

Comment: [Wolfram MathWorld's Hyperplane Definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperplane.html): "More generally, a hyperplane is any codimension-1 vector subspace of a vector space. Equivalently, a hyperplane `V` in a vector space `W` is any subspace such that `W/V` is one-dimensional."